# How to use delayed expansion on a variable like %%a or %1?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, indirection, delayedvariableexpansion

I'm trying to make a batch file I call from another batch file, but the variables don't work, all the results are "a", while the expected result would be option1=a, option2=b, etc.

Here's the code to demonstrate the issue:

```bat
call temp.bat a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t e u v w x y z
pause
exit
```

and for temp.bat:

```bat
set Number=0
for %%a in (%*) do set /a Number+=1

for /l %%a in (1,1,%Number%) do (
    set option%%a=%1
    shift
)
exit /b
```

I've tried `!%1!` with empty results; `%%1%` gave "%1" as the result; `%1%` had the same result as just using `%1`

Comment: [Argument references](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) and [`for` meta-variables](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) are something completely different than [environment variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html), and [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) only affects the latter…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with one `FOR` command which would be much more efficient.

Using the CALL Method

```
@echo off

set Number=0
for %%a in (%*) do (
    set /a Number+=1
    call set "option%%Number%%=%%a"
)
```

Using Delayed Expansion

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Number=0
for %%a in (%*) do (
    set /a Number+=1
    set "option!Number!=%%a"
)
```

Comment: both work, but this one works much better in my specific situation (more efficient)

Answer (score 3):

You can force another level of indirection by using `call`. It'll expand `%%1` to `%1` before evaluating

```bat
for /l %%a in (1,1,%Number%) do (
    call set option%%a=%%1
    shift
)
```

- [Batch number variable setter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2999414/995714)
- [BAT-file: variable contents as part of another variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9700256/995714)
- [How can I pass a variable name as part of a parameter to a batch file and then use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10231334/995714)

See also an alternative here: [Batch-Script - Iterate through arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19835849/995714)